# <ctgmath> header seems to be nonfunctional?

Tags: c++, floating-point, tgmath

I'm working on some numerical simulation code, so I'm very conscious of the floating point types I use and often switch between `float`, `double`, and `long double`. I found out that tgmath.h is supposed to solve this issue by providing useful macros, but I'm unable to get it to work! In the following code, `sqrt(10.0f)` returns the full double precision square root, while `sqrtf` behaves as expected.

```cpp
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(16);
    std::cout<<sqrt(10.0f)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<sqrtf(10.0f)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect this to output the same number twice, since `sqrt(float)` should evaluate to `sqrtf(float)` via tgmath's functionality. Instead, it outputs the double floating precision value, then the single precision value.

```
3.16227766016838 
3.162277698516846
```

I'm on Ubuntu, and I'm compiling using the command `g++ floattest.cpp -std=c++11 -o floattest`. Higher versions of C++ behave the same, and lower versions `-std=c++03` and `-std=c++98` both fail to compile with `error: ‘__builtin_tgmath’ was not declared in this scope`. The compilation error does say `In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/tgmath.h`.

Is it the case that yes, the headers I have totally ignore tgmath.h? How would I run old C++ code that relies on tgmath.h? For my current project I can just define my own C++11 _Generics, but it would be nice to know what is going on.

Ubuntu version: 22.04
g++ version: g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

Comment: You should try `std::sqrt`, which is overloaded for different types. The C version `sqrt` is only for `double`.

Comment: if you're in C++ why not just use the already overloaded `std` variants?  e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt.  isn't tgmath just about using macros to make C++ overloading of these available to C code?

Comment: @Sam Well, on my platform (VS 2022), the "tgmath.h" header has an `#ifndef __cplusplus ... #endif` block surrounding the vast majority of the content. So, when using C++, effectively nothing is defined in that header. Can't speak for the OP's platform, though.

Comment: Well, all it does is `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: @AdrianMole sorry, didn't explain that well!  the C++ stl `cmath` header already has these functions overloaded appropriately, hence there didn't seem to be much point in including them into a C++ codebase.  just looked at my clang (16) header and it also disables the header when compiled from C++ source (via the same `__cplusplus` preprocesser check)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I never realized how weird the situation was, that including cmath gives two separate functions `sqrt` and `std::sqrt`. cppreference also says that tgmath just includes other headers and does nothing else, which seems a bit weird. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: @David not sure if you've played around with Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer before, but it can be interesting to see what it makes of your code.  here's some fiddling I've done trying to show some variants: https://godbolt.org/z/PafjKhEae

Answer (score 0):

`<tgmath.h>` in C++ is defined as (by [[tgmath.h.syn]](https://wg21.link/tgmath.h.syn)):

> ```cpp
> #include <cmath>
> #include <complex>
> ```

... Which does not guarantee that a function called `::sqrt` is defined.

In glibc, these signatures are exposed:

```cpp
// (In the global :: namespace, defined by including <math.h>)
float sqrtf(float);
double sqrt(double);
long double sqrtl(long double);

// (Added for C++ <cmath>)
namespace std {
    float sqrtf(float);
    long double sqrtl(long double);

    float sqrt(float);
    double sqrt(double);
    long double sqrt(long double);
}
```

So `sqrt(10.0f)` only finds `::sqrt(double)`, converting it to a double.

To get the C behaviour of `_Generic` in a macro selecting the right function, use the overloaded `std::sqrt`.

A quick fix for old (and incorrect) C++ code is `using std::sqrt;` in the global namespace, but it's better in the long run to just port `sqrt`->`std::sqrt`